# Node JS, Extendscript and Adobe premiere pro a complete automation possible?

Tags: node.js, automation, adobe, extendscript, adobe-premiere

I am trying to automate Adobe Premiere Pro video editing and I am downloading files from the cloud. I am not sure how to use, or give a trigger from nodejs to the extend script, anyone here who has worked on this might help me.

Along with that I want to know what is the current state of the video automation, there are not many tutorials or guides which can help out the Extend script path, is it really outdated?
If so are there lots of people working on Da Vinci automation?

We have automated the uploading the file to the Adobe Premiere Pro and the part where it directly uploads the files to the sequence in proper order.